# Eclipse/Java always beyond 100% CPU usage in OpenSuse 12.2

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, cpu-usage, opensuse

I am using Eclipse for basic android development along with chrome browser on my laptop and i see that eclipse alone is taking beyond 100% CPU everytime.

[image]

My system properties are as below:

**Linux Distro**

```
cat /etc/issue

Welcome to openSUSE 12.2 "Mantis" - Kernel \r (\l).
```

**Kernel**

```
uname -a

Linux linux-b4rl.site 3.4.47-2.38-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 31 20:17:40 UTC 2013 (3961086) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**JAVA Version**

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.1) (suse-3.41.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b50, mixed mode)
```

As you can see i am not running any emulator and chrome is not using any JRE plugin.

My laptop is Dell Inspiron N5110 with Core i5 (2.30 Ghz + 4 GB RAM) and this sluggish performance of java on linux compared to windows breaks my heart.

Any suggestions why JVM is eating up the CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how but the problem got away after i cleared eclipse console and it became totally responsive. 
Seems like console filter regex was taking too much cpu

Answer (score 0):

This will most likely be caused by one of the installed Eclipse plugins. I suggest disabling the plugins one by one until you found which one causes the problems ("Help/About Eclipse/Installation details").

I would also try to start Eclipse using the -clean argument so it gets reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different IDE (e.g. [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/), which supports Linux well) and check if the problem persists. If other IDEs do not have a problem, you can pin-point it to Eclipse, if other IDEs cause the same issue, you need to search in your system's setup.